# Is there any solution to export drilldown charts too when exporting multiple charts to PDF

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to export multiple charts to PDF file. Here i am providing a demo which contains a pie chart with two drill down charts. When i click on export all button only main pie chart is exported to pdf. But i want to export the two drill down charts to PDF file with it.

Comment: Here is my code that i created just for a demo http://jsfiddle.net/upendrasharma221/zma6xzk0/

Comment: In the same PDF file right? Not three separate PDFs?

Comment: Yes in the same PDF file

Comment: Do you have any solution for this, plz update in the given url

Comment: In the exporting you should create 3 charts, each of them as separated object with defined data.

Comment: How to get the data when click when click on export button and define the object for each chart

Comment: Can you give an short example for this.

Comment: So you need to catch "current" status and chart when you export or three charts with each level?

Comment: I want three charts (one is main chart and two are drill down charts) to the pdf

Comment: With their default attributes (title, legends, labels, axislabels etc)

Comment: Waiting for solution

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: Is this possible or not ?